# Intraday (non-tick) Historical Data - Bloomberg Python API

Tags: programming, bloomberg

Is it possible to get hourly or minute-by-minute data (in the form of a dataframe) in Python using one of the API wrappers (`xbbg` or `pdblp`)? Using the former, `blp.bdh` and `blp.bdip` don't seem to work. The latter only gives bar data, which I understand isn't available for more than 140 days.

Comment: You cannot get data further back than 140 days with the API.

Comment: Hi I believe that is true for tick data...but I can get hourly or 1-min data perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It's really a help desk question (`F1 F1` will not support the Python API, but `WAPI` will have the info) - and they most likely will guide you to `HELP DAPI` - Constructing Formulas - BDH: Intraday Bars - BDH Intraday Bars Description (Python and Excel both use the same C++ API)

The direct link in `IB` is {LPHP DAPI:0:1 2754468 }

The first section states: "Note: Historical intraday data is available a maximum of 140 days ago." If you try a date outside this range, you will get no response (#N/A N/A) in Excel.

There is no way a standard BBG subscription (API) can give you more intraday history (Bar Data is intraday data after all).

There are some exceptions, like FX, where you have `BFIX` which is tickerized for the fixing times. However, for essentially all other data, this limit applies.